# Why won't CSS render around an element containing nil?

Tags: html, css, json, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have a problem with CSS not working properly in a combination of HAML, Backbone-text-injection, and some Rails JSON rendering.

The offending code is here:

```
%td{:class => 'zone_a'}
  = start_time(z.zone, 'A')
```

start_time just does :

```
def start_time(zone, letter)
    if zone
       program = zone.programs.where(:identifier => letter).first
    if program
       program_zone = ProgramZone.where(:program_id => program.id, :zone_id => zone.id).first
      if program_zone.run_time.to_i > 946684800
        return program_zone.run_time.strftime("%H:%M")
      else
        return nil
      end
    else
      return nil
    end
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
```

And the nil which is returned renders in the page.

Let's look at what it looks like when we have a box with a value and then three boxes with nil:

[image: The offending boxes]

The top and bottom black borders called from the %tr.inspection_zone element, that is supposed to affect all %td elements in the entire row, is having no effect here.

So this is the question - a legit SO question.

I "solved" this by putting in a non-breaking space:

```
%td{:class => 'zone_a'}
    = "&nbsp;".html_safe + start_time(z.zone, 'A')
```

What I'm looking for is not a work-around but rather a reason why CSS won't effect an element with a nil text/html value.  And from that reason, there is probably a better solution than what I've done.  I feel like my approach is just duct-taping a busted pipe.

EDIT:

Adding the rendered HTML:

Without the

```
<td class="zone_b"></td>
```

With the

```
<td class="zone_b">
                &nbsp;
              </td>
```

Here is an image of the CSS - it's the same either way:

[image: Rendered CSS]

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML and CSS for the element that is not showing up. If there is none then it's not a CSS issue, but rather something on the backend

Comment: does adding "border-collapse: collapse;" fix it?